# How to keep odd/even background colors on selection?

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, celltable

I have a GWT `DataGrid` (CellTable) with different background colors for odd/even rows:

```
.dataGridEvenRow { background: white !important; }
.dataGridEvenRowCell { border: selectionBorderWidth solid white !important; }
.dataGridOddRow { background: red !important; }
.dataGridOddRowCell { border: selectionBorderWidth solid red !important; }
```

On selection, I only want to change the border color, but the background should not be changed. But when I'm using styles as follows, the background IS always changed to '`white`'.

```
/* Here something must be wrong */
.dataGridSelectedRow {
  background: inherit !important;
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

That's the inner background of the cells. But it does not inherit from the odd/even rows, but somehow from somewher else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the following styles:

```
.dataGridSelectedRow {
  color: inherit !important;
}

.dataGridSelectedRowCell {
  background: inherit;
  border: selectionBorderWidth solid inherit !important;
}
```

Important is to not use !important on the background property there. Don't know why, but it only works this way.

Answer (score 0):

in your css try this:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

these are pseudo class selectors in css, please let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: `org.w3c.css.sac.CSSParseException: invalid pseudo function name nth-of-type(
    at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.pseudo(Parser.java:2038)
    at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.simple_selector(Parser.java:1604)
    at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.selector(Parser.java:1519)`